# How to get day of the week based on inputed date(Python)

Tags: python, datetime, time, weekday

So i wanted the user to enter date and based on that day to get named day of the week, for example today's date is 2022.11.10,  so wanted answer would be Thursday.
I know this is wrong, can anybody help?

```
import datetime

def dayOfTheWeek(day, month, year):
    date = datetime.date(year, month, day)
    weekday = date.weekday()
    day_dict = { 0 : "Monday", 1 : "Tuesday", 2 : "Wednesday", 3 : "Thursday", 4 : "Friday", 5 : "Sturday", 6 : "Sunday"}
    
    for key in day_dict.key():
        if weekday == key:
            return day[key]
        
year = int(input("Year: "))     
month = int(input("Month: "))       
day = int(input("Day: "))

dayOfTheWeek(day, month, year)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of going through the dictionary with for loop, you can simply return the result already converted by dictionary:

```
import datetime

def dayOfTheWeek(day, month, year):
    date = datetime.date(year, month, day)
    weekday = date.weekday()
    day_dict = { 0 : "Monday", 1 : "Tuesday", 2 : "Wednesday", 3 : "Thursday", 4 : "Friday", 5 : "Sturday", 6 : "Sunday"}

    return day_dict[weekday]
    
year = int(input("Year: "))     
month = int(input("Month: "))       
day = int(input("Day: "))

dayOfTheWeek(day, month, year)
```

Comment: Thats it! Greatful!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
from datetime import datetime

date = datetime(year=2022, month=11, day=10)  
weekday_name = date.strftime('%A')
print(weekday_name)
```

See [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-strftime-function/) for further information about strftime function.